# Crystal If doesn't work

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the following function

```
def fcn(lst)
  if (lst.size == 0) 
      return [] of Int32
  end
  lc = lst.map{|a| a[1]}
end
```

When doing:

```
lst = [] of Int32
puts(fcn(lst))
```

I get:

> Error in line 8: instantiating 'fcn(Array(Int32))'
>   in line 5: undefined method '[]' for Int32

It seems "if" is not taken into account. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Could you please see the documentations about Crystal Syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

In `lst.map{|a| a[1]}`, `lst` is `Array(Int32)`, so `a` is `Int32`, and `Int32` doesn't have a `[]` method. In Ruby Fixnum does have the `[]` method, to return 1 if the bit in that position is set. I don't know if that's what you want to do. If so, use the `bit` method.